# How to print the name of a function whenever it is called without adding printfs?

Tags: c, list, function, call, store

I am looking for a **method to print (store) name of any function** when it is called.

I don't want to add traces or prints in all the functions.

I am looking for some method which I can enable from the top and it prints/stores/lists the function names called.

The programming language I use is C.

It may not be a standard function, I am ok if I have to add a hack somewhere to make it work.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I'm pretty sure you can use `__cyg_profile_func_enter` in GCC to get the function address passed in on each function call, and there might be something to get the name from that, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at `gcc` `-pg` option and `gprof` profiler tool.

http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/